# Do source maps work when debugging?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gulp, uglifyjs, source-maps

I'm using gulp with gulp-uglify, gulp-concat and gulp-sourcemaps to minify/concatenate my js files and produce source maps.

When I open chrome dev-tool in the sources tab, I can see the minified file along a "source" directory with all the original files - as expected.
But when I try to debug or get an error in the console, then the references are to the minified file (for example, error traces in the console, point to a line in the minified file...).

Is this how source-maps works? or I did something wrong?

My gulp js conf - [gulpfile](https://gist.github.com/danielyogel/132963317ed8ecf38b6a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [source maps](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps) the console should point you to the original file.

Here I intentionally wrote some code that breaks jQuery's internal code. As you can see, the console brings me right to the original file and line. I only included the minified jQuery file.
[image]

If for some reason it is not working, make sure "Enable JavaScript source maps" is checked:
[image]

I'm not familiar with Gulpjs but just make sure the path of the map is correct.

Comment: I'm doubting this has anything to do with Gulp.

Answer (score 0):

I believe gulp-uglify strips it. i checked the github there seems to be some fixes for it now but still an open issue: https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/issues/56
There should be a .map file btw